# csv file import to mysql date format

Tags: php, mysql, date, csv

I have a csv file that I'm importing into mysql, there is a date field in the csv file that is formatted as so: 30.09.2011

I have a php page that pulls the data from the database and I want to order it by date field. At the moment it is seeing the date as a string and ordering like so..

30.09.2011
6.02.2012
7.10.2011
9.12.2008

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use PHP for this. Correct it at the source. That is, add a new column in the MySQL table of datatype `DATE`.

Then you can populate it after your import using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

```
UPDATE your_table SET new_date_column = STR_TO_DATE(old_str_column,'%d.%m.%Y');
```

Doing so will make sorting, as well as calculation, formatting, etc easier in the future.

Comment: You should *mark* the answer that best solved your question by clicking the checkmark on the right. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried this with '%m/%d/%y' to no avail. Any reason this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the data in the CSV on a regular basis, why not just modify the extract SQL so that the date comes out in the right format for MySQL to suck it in?

If you are extracting from oracle for example, you can change

```
select
    yourDateColumn
from
    yourTable
```

to

```
select
    to_char(yourDateColumn, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as yourMySQLDateColumn
from
    yourTable
```

Then you can import directly into a date datatype in Mysql, but you can then also skip the whole PHP upload and move right on to the [MySQL Load Data Infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command, which will be a STACK faster than anything that PHP will do.